# Using cURL to upload POST data with files,I got a 500 error

Tags: curl

```
curl -k -X POST -F "file=@/1.png; filename='1.png'" -v http://mammo.neuralrad.com:5300/upload
```

The problem I am getting is as follows:

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 184.60.26.204:5300...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to mammo.neuralrad.com (184.60.26.204) port 5300 (#0)
> POST /upload HTTP/1.1
> Host: mammo.neuralrad.com:5300
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 120566
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------b9445a7e855e67c5
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 291
< Server: Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.6.8
< Date: Tue, 31 May 2022 02:55:13 GMT
< 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
* Closing connection 0
```

It is normal for normal browser access to upload, and 500 will not appear.

How do I adjust my cURL commands accordingly ?

Comment: You would need to work with the developers of the server to work out what error actually occurred; ideally there would be additional checks to ensure that the server won't error out, allowing a 4xx response for the client to handle.

Comment: Also, "Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.", it is possible the server is overloaded ✌️

Comment: @msbit,I found something new, 'submit': 'Analyze', I missed this

Comment: Alright, after a bit of futzing around, I think if you get rid of the `'` surrounding the `filename` value, you'll be fine. So, something like `-F "file=@/1.png; filename=1.png"` ✌️

Comment: I think you are missing the `file` field. `curl -v -F file=@your_image.png "http://mammo.neuralrad.com:5300/upload"` should work.